# redux-saga/loadable-component first fetch not waited, but all the next ones yes

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I can't make a proper server side.

When I start my server and make a fetch for example `http://localhost:3000/last-movie-releases`

**The first fetch is not waited** by `toPromise()`. But ***all the other ones I do next*** are good, server side is then alright.

Just a snippet my code below. I dispatch my redux action in the class constructor. (like everybody does)

```
  store
    .runSaga(rootSaga)
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('sagas complete');
      const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(jsx);
      const css = sheets.toString();
      res.send(
        renderFullPage(html, css, serialize(store.getState()))
      );
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e.message);
      res.status(500).send(e.message);
    });

  ReactDOMServer.renderToString(jsx);

  store.close();
```

***Is it a normal behavior ?***

PS : My saga making the fetch I am talking about starts with a `fork`, then a `fork` again, and a `call`. Exactly like in the [real-word repo](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/examples/real-world)

I am wondering if I missed a return somewhere.

```
/***********************************************
***************** UPDATE BELOW *****************
***********************************************/
```

I give you my sagas (there is just 2)

```
import {
  take,
  put,
  call,
  fork,
  select,
  delay,
  all,
  takeEvery,
  takeLatest
} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as api from './api';

import * as actions from '../actions';

// each entity defines 3 creators { request, success, failure }
const { movies, movie } = actions;

function* fetchEntity(entity, apiFn, body) {
  yield put(entity.request(body));
  const { response, error } = yield call(apiFn, body);
  if (response) yield put(entity.success(body, response));
  else yield put(entity.failure(body, error));
}

// yeah! we can also bind Generators
export const fetchMovies = fetchEntity.bind(null, movies, api.fetchMovies);
export const fetchMovie = fetchEntity.bind(null, movie, api.fetchMovie);

/******************************************************************************/
/********************************* SAGAS **************************************/
/******************************************************************************/

function* sagaFetchMovies() {
  yield call(fetchMovies);
}
function* sagaFetchMovie(movieId) {
  yield call(fetchMovie, movieId);
}

/******************************************************************************/
/******************************* WATCHERS *************************************/
/******************************************************************************/

function* watchFetchMovies() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(actions.FETCH_MOVIES);
    yield fork(sagaFetchMovies);
  }
}

function* watchFetchMovie() {
  while (true) {
    const { movieId } = yield take(actions.FETCH_MOVIE);
    yield fork(sagaFetchMovie, movieId);
  }
}

export default function* root() {
  yield all([fork(watchFetchMovies), fork(watchFetchMovie)]);
}
```

```
/***********************************************
***************** UPDATE BELOW *****************
***********************************************/
```

I show you where I dispatch my action ;)

```
...
class Movie extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isSlideShowOpened: false };

    const movie = props.app.movie.results.filter(e => e.id === Number(props.match.params.movieId));

    if (movie.length === 0) {
      props.fetchMovie(props.match.params.movieId); // <---- I dispatch here because componentWillMount is deprecated :s
    }
  }
...
```

```
...
class Movies extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    if (props.app.movies.results.length === 0) {
      props.fetchMovies(); // <---- I dispatch here because componentWillMount is deprecated :s
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: You should give [`yield`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.html) a try. It allows you to make asynchronous requests within your saga.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

#### There is a big caveat with [@loadable/component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loadable/component) server side rendering **lol**

**@loadable/component** forces you to split the code for each of your routes, and eventually use a fallback (spinner when downloading the js bundle)

Let me remind you **@loadable/component** is the only module on the market able to do split code for server side rendering lol

## Well none of your sagas will be waited by ***@loadable/component***. I don't have an alternative, this isn't that bad for google and bing I think...

My react router looks like something like this for example

```
import React from 'react';
import loadable from '@loadable/component';
import Loading from './Exception/Loading';

const Home = loadable(() => import('./Home/index'), { fallback: <Loading /> });
const Movies = loadable(() => import('./Movies/index'), { fallback: <Loading /> });
const Movie = loadable(() => import('./Movie/index'), { fallback: <Loading /> });

const Slide1 = loadable(() => import('./Slides/Slide1'), { fallback: <Loading /> });

const Forbidden = loadable(() => import('./Exception/403'));
const NoMatch = loadable(() => import('./Exception/404'));
const ServerDown = loadable(() => import('./Exception/500'));

const indexRoutes = [
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/last-movie-releases',
    component: Movies
  },
  {
    path: '/movie-details/:movieId/:slideshow?',
    component: Movie
  },
  {
    path: '/slide1',
    component: Slide1
  },
  { path: '/403', component: Forbidden },
  { path: '/404', component: NoMatch },
  { path: '/500', component: ServerDown },
  { name: 'NoMatch', component: NoMatch }
];

export default indexRoutes;
```

Comment: Sorry, but you are incorrect in almost every sentence. Especially as well as `loadable-components` works during the rendering, and sagas are working before.

Comment: Plus - `loadable-components` would __never__ render `loading` component at SSR. At SSR `loadable` is 100% synchronous. It's nodejs! - you might just `require` what you need, and be given.

Comment: This should be your question edit, not an answer. Hardcoded routes? It doesnt look very well...